# making single client and server

Tags: java

I have written a client server program:

```
 {
  import java.net.*;
  class verify {
  public static int serverPort=998;
  public static int clientPort=999;
  public static int buffer_size=1024;
  public static DatagramSocket ds;
  public static byte buffer[]=new byte[buffer_size];

  public static void TheServer() throws Exception { 
   int pos=0;
   while (true) {
     int c=System.in.read();
     switch(c) {
        case -1:
          System.out.println("server quits");
           return;
        case '\r':
           break;
        case '\n':
           ds.send(new DatagramPacket(buffer,pos,InetAddress.getLocalHost(),clientPort)) ;
           pos=0;
           break;
        default:
           buffer[pos++] = (byte) c;
     }
   }
  }

 public static void TheClient()throws Exception {
   while(true) {
     DatagramPacket p=new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
     ds.receive(p);
     System.out.println(new String(p.getData(),0,p.getLength()));
   }
 }

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
  if(args.length==1) {
    ds=new DatagramSocket(serverPort);
    TheServer();
  } else {
     ds=new DatagramSocket(clientPort);
     TheClient();
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Can I make my pc both server and client.If yes please suggest a way out.

Comment: Please use the code formatting feature. The code in your post is difficult to read.

Comment: @ Mudassir  improved the code

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your PC can absolutely be both the server and the client.  How to get there from your code I cannot say, however.

Generally though, in `TheServer()` you will want to create a `ServerSocket` and set it to listen on `serverPort`.  Then do something like `Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept()` to wait for and accept the next incoming connection.

Then in `TheClient()` you create a new `Socket` to "localhost" on `serverPort`.  This will connect your server and client.

Note that because `serverSocket.accept()` blocks, your server and client *cannot* share the same thread.  So you can either run two separate instance of your application as you seem to be doing now, or you can use `main()` to set up a new thread for `TheServer()` and then start it before you call `TheClient()`.

Comment: @Suhail - Thanks, that's much more readable.  Is there any particular reason why you're using `DatagramSocket` instead of `ServerSocket` and `Socket`?

Comment: No,not any particular reason.I just want to pass messages

Answer (score 0):

As long as the client and server sends and receives on different ports, then there is no reason that you cannot have both client and server running on the same machine. In fact, I did this quite often during my university years while I was testing client/server applications.

Comment: @Suhail Gupta - No, different. So use, for example, 3000 for server sending, 3001 for server listening, 3002 for client sending and 3003 for client listening.